# R Rcpp return list of class objects in module

Tags: r, rcpp

I tried to simplify my situation to the following setup. I have an C++ implementation of a Class, lets call it `Serie`. I make use of this Class in R by using the module setup. This worked beautifully for me, since I only returned standard vectors of doubles so far (as I tried to demonstrate with the `doubleSer` method in the code below). Now is where my problem starts:
I wrote a method of the class, which returns a vector of objects of that class (I tried to demonstrate this with the `subSeriesPairs` method). Now, I was expecting the code to break, when I add this method to the module (the line which is commented out in the example below), since of cause R does not know how to deal with a vector of objects, right? But How do I fix this? Is it possible to do something like that? Any help, link or hint is appreciated.
I hope the example below runs on your setup, and if not illustrates my problem nevertheless.

serie.h

```
namespace seriePkg
{
  class Serie {
    private:
      std::vector<double> m_data;
    public:
      Serie (std::vector<double> d) : m_data(d){};
      std::vector<double> doubleSer();
      std::vector<Serie> subSeriesPairs();
    
  }
}
```

serie.cpp

```
#include "serie.h"
using namespace seriePkg;

std::vector<double> Serie::doubleSer(){
  std::vector<double> retVec;
  for(std::vector<double>::iterator it = m_data.begin(); it != m_data.end(); it++ ){
    retVec.push_back(*it * 2);
  }
  return retVec;
}

std::vector<Serie> Serie::subSeriesPairs(){
  std::vector<Serie> ssp;
  std::deque<double> runSubSetValue;
  for(std::vector<double>::iterator it = m_data.begin(); it != m_data.end(); it++ ){
    runSubSetValue.push_back(*it);
    while(runSubSetValue.size() > 2L ){
      runSubSetValue.pop_front();
    }
    ssp.push_back( Serie({runSubSetValue.begin(), runSubSetValue.end()} );
  }
  return subSeries;
}
```

series_modul.cpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "serie.h"

using namespace seriePkg;

RCPP_MODULE(series_modul) {
  using namespace Rcpp;
  class_<seriePkg::Serie>("Serie_cppClass")
  .constructor< std::vector<double> >()
  .method("doubleTime", &seriePkg::Serie::doubleSer, "double the data vec")
  //.method("subSeriesPairs", &seriePkg::Serie::subSeriesPairs, "list of subsets of size 2")
  ;
}
```

Comment: You need to help the compiler with a converter from `Serie` to a `SEXP` type.

Comment: Can't you rewrite using `Rcpp::NumericVector` in place of `std::vector<double>` and `Rcpp::List` in place of `std::vector<Serie>`?

Comment: `std::vector<double>` is fine; we have that covered as a STL wrapper around a plain old type.  But for newly created types the compiler cannot guess what is needed.

Comment: Thanks so much Mr. Eddelbuettel, but how can I help the compiler.Is there an example out there on how to do so?

Comment: I tried to figure it out what you mean by converting. When investigating this, I keep coming back to the `as` and ´wrap´ templates. However this confuses me, since I thought of the module and the class template within the module as exactly that, a wrapper around the C++ class in order to enable R handling. Therefore I feel going in circles...

Comment: Your code seems to be incomplete, e.g. what are `subSeries` and  `irregTS::TimeSeries`? However, the question of `as` and `wrap` extension for modules is handled by the `RCPP_EXPOSED_*` macros. See section "2.2.11. ExtendingRcpp::asandRcpp::wrap" at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-modules.pdf#page=7. You can also search for the different `RCPP_EXPOSED_*` macros here on SO, as they have been discussed multiple times.

Comment: Your right, there were leftovers from the original code from which I tried to simlified it from. Thanks a lot for the hint with the RCPP_EXPOSED_ Macro and the vignette. I'll check it out!

Comment: Found It! For me the sollution was to add `RCPP_EXPOSED_ CLASS(seriePkg::Serie)` before the module. Thanks to Ralf for the hint and of cause to Dirk for implementing this thing. To me you guys are coding rockstars... :)

Comment: Great that you found the solution! How about adding a self-answer with a working example?

Answer (score 2):

In the above setup, the sollution to me was to just add `RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(seriePkg::Serie)` before the module. So in the described example the class files stayed untuched and only the modul file was slightly changed to:

series_modul.cpp

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include "serie.h"

using namespace seriePkg;

RCPP_EXPOSED_CLASS(seriePkg::Serie) // <- new line to add 

RCPP_MODULE(series_modul) {
  using namespace Rcpp;
  class_<seriePkg::Serie>("Serie_cppClass")
  .constructor< std::vector<double> >()
  .method("doubleTime", &seriePkg::Serie::doubleSer, "double the data vec")
  .method("subSeriesPairs", &seriePkg::Serie::subSeriesPairs, "list of subsets of size 2")
  ;
}
```